JSON processing with php for mysql insert
I have a rather large and (to me) complex JSON string that I have decoded, but am bashing my head trying to iterate through the decoded array.
Here is a snippet of the json code:
"10:40 31 Dec 2024 BA0457 MAD  LHR 14:10 31 Dec 2024 BA0115 LHR  JFK": {
    "flights": [
        {
            "i": 0,
            "offPeak": false,
            "airlineName": "British Airways",
            "flightNumber": "BA0457",
            "origin": "MAD",
            "destination": "LHR",
            "stops": 0,
            "departure": "10:40 31 Dec 2024",
            "arrival": "12:10 31 Dec 2024",
            "cabinClasses": {
                "J": true
            },
            "aircraft": "Airbus A320 jet"
        },
        {
            "i": 1,
            "offPeak": false,
            "airlineName": "British Airways",
            "flightNumber": "BA0115",
            "origin": "LHR",
            "destination": "JFK",
            "stops": 0,
            "departure": "14:10 31 Dec 2024",
            "arrival": "17:20 31 Dec 2024",
            "cabinClasses": {
                "J": true
            },
            "aircraft": "Boeing 777 jet"
        }
    ],
    "availability": {
        "Y": false,
        "W": false,
        "J": true
    },
    "timestamp": "Thu Oct 17 2024 13:58:11 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)",
    "duration": "12h 40m"
}, **// this repeats indefinitely ...**

It seems I have several nested foreach loops to contend with, but I'm having issues understanding this array structure once it is decoded:
Array ( [data] => Array ( [10:40 31 Dec 2024 BA0457 MAD LHR 14:10 31 Dec 2024 BA0115 LHR JFK] => Array ( [flights] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [i] => 0 [offPeak] => [airlineName] => British Airways [flightNumber] => BA0457 [origin] => MAD [destination] => LHR [stops] => 0 [departure] => 10:40 31 Dec 2024 [arrival] => 12:10 31 Dec 2024 [cabinClasses] => Array ( [J] => 1 ) [aircraft] => Airbus A320 jet ) [1] => Array ( [i] => 1 [offPeak] => [airlineName] => British Airways [flightNumber] => BA0115 [origin] => LHR [destination] => JFK [stops] => 0 [departure] => 14:10 31 Dec 2024 [arrival] => 17:20 31 Dec 2024 [cabinClasses] => Array ( [J] => 1 ) [aircraft] => Boeing 777 jet ) ) [availability] => Array ( [Y] => [W] => [J] => 1 ) [timestamp] => Thu Oct 17 2024 13:58:11 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) [duration] => 12h 40m ) [06:55 31 Dec 2024 IB0711 MAD LHR 11:20 31 Dec 2024 BA0173 LHR JFK] => Array ( [flights] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [i] => 0 [offPeak] => [airlineName] => Iberia [flightNumber] => IB0711 [origin] => MAD [destination] => LHR [stops] => 0 [departure] => 06:55 31 Dec 2024 [arrival] => 08:25 31 Dec 2024 [cabinClasses] => Array ( [Y] => 2 ) [aircraft] => Airbus A320 jet ) [1] => Array ( [i] => 1 [offPeak] => [airlineName] => British Airways [flightNumber] => BA0173 [origin] => LHR [destination] => JFK [stops] => 0 [departure] => 11:20 31 Dec 2024 [arrival] => 14:20 31 Dec 2024 [cabinClasses] => Array ( [W] => 2 ) [aircraft] => Boeing 777 jet ) ) [availability] => Array ( [Y] => [W] => 2 [J] => ) [timestamp] => Thu Oct 17 2024 13:58:11 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) [duration] => 13h 25m ) [07:45 31 Dec 2024 IB0713 MAD LHR 11:20 31 Dec 2024 BA0173 LHR JFK] => Array ( [flights] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [i] => 0 [offPeak] => [airlineName] => Iberia [flightNumber] => IB0713 [origin] => MAD [destination] => LHR [stops] => 0 [departure] => 07:45 31 Dec 2024 [arrival] => 09:15 31 Dec 2024 [cabinClasses] => Array ( [Y] => 2 ) [aircraft] => Airbus A320 jet ) [1] => Array ( [i] => 1 [offPeak] => [airlineName] => British Airways [flightNumber] => BA0173 [origin] => LHR [destination] => JFK [stops] => 0 [departure] => 11:20 31 Dec 2024 [arrival] => 14:20 31 Dec 2024 [cabinClasses] => Array ( [W] => 2 ) [aircraft] => Boeing 777 jet ) ) [availability] => Array ( [Y] => [W] => 2 [J] => ) [timestamp] => Thu Oct 17 2024 13:58:11 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) [duration] => 12h 35m ) [12:30 31 Dec 2024 BA0467 MAD LHR 16:25 31 Dec 2024 BA0113 LHR JFK] => Array ( [flights] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [i] => 0 [offPeak] => [airlineName] => British Airways [flightNumber] => BA0467 [origin] => MAD [destination] => LHR [stops] => 0 [departure] => 12:30 31 Dec 2024 [arrival] => 14:00 31 Dec 2024 [cabinClasses] => Array ( [Y] => 6 [W] => [J] => 1 ) [aircraft] => Airbus A321 Neo ) [1] => Array ( [i] => 1 [offPeak] => [airlineName] => British Airways [flightNumber] => BA0113 [origin] => LHR [destination] => JFK [stops] => 0 [departure] => 16:25 31 Dec 2024 [arrival] => 19:35 31 Dec 2024 [cabinClasses] => Array ( [Y] => 6 [W] => 5 [J] => 1 ) [aircraft] => Boeing 787 jet ) ) [availability] => Array ( [Y] => 6 [W] => 5 [J] => 1 ) [timestamp] => Thu Oct 17 2024 13:58:11 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) [duration] => 13h 05m ) [14:20 31 Dec 2024 BA0469 MAD LHR 18:00 31 Dec 2024 BA0179 LHR JFK] => Array ( [flights] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [i] => 0 [offPeak] => [airlineName] => British Airways [flightNumber] => BA0469 [origin] => MAD [destination] => LHR [stops] => 0 [departure] => 14:20 31 Dec 2024 [arrival] => 15:50 31 Dec 2024 [cabinClasses] => Array ( [Y] => 5 [W] => [J] => 1 ) [aircraft] => Airbus A320 jet ) [1] => Array ( [i] => 1 [offPeak] => [airlineName] => British Airways [flightNumber] => BA0179 [origin] => LHR [destination] => JFK [stops] => 0 [departure] => 18:00 31 Dec 2024 [arrival] => 21:10 31 Dec 2024 [cabinClasses] => Array ( [Y] => 5 [W] => 6 [J] => 1 ) [aircraft] => Boeing 777 jet ) ) [availability] => Array ( [Y] => 5 [W] => 2 [J] => 1 ) [timestamp] => Thu Oct 17 2024 13:58:11 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) [duration] => 12h 50m ) [16:45 31 Dec 2024 IB0723 MAD LHR 19:50 31 Dec 2024 BA0183 LHR JFK] => Array ( [flights] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [i] => 0 [offPeak] => [airlineName] => Iberia [flightNumber] => IB0723 [origin] => MAD [destination] => LHR [stops] => 0 [departure] => 16:45 31 Dec 2024 [arrival] => 18:15 31 Dec 2024 [cabinClasses] => Array ( [J] => 1 ) [aircraft] => Airbus A320 jet ) [1] => Array ( [i] => 1 [offPeak] => [airlineName] => British Airways [flightNumber] => BA0183 [origin] => LHR [destination] => JFK [stops] => 0 [departure] => 19:50 31 Dec 2024 [arrival] => 22:55 31 Dec 2024 [cabinClasses] => Array ( [J] => 1 ) [aircraft] => Boeing 777 jet ) ) [availability] => Array ( [Y] => [W] => [J] => 1 ) [timestamp] => Thu Oct 17 2024 13:58:11 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) [duration] => 12h 10m ) [11:15 31 Dec 2024 BA0459 MAD LHR 14:10 31 Dec 2024 BA0115 LHR JFK] => Array ( [flights] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [i] => 0 [offPeak] => [airlineName] => British Airways [flightNumber] => BA0459 [origin] => MAD [destination] => LHR [stops] => 0 [departure] => 11:15 31 Dec 2024 [arrival] => 12:45 31 Dec 2024 [cabinClasses] => Array ( [J] => 1 ) [aircraft] => Airbus A320 jet ) [1] => Array ( [i] => 1 [offPeak] => [airlineName] => British Airways [flightNumber] => BA0115 [origin] => LHR [destination] => JFK [stops] => 0 [departure] => 14:10 31 Dec 2024 [arrival] => 17:20 31 Dec 2024 [cabinClasses] => Array ( [J] => 1 ) [aircraft] => Boeing 777 jet ) ) [availability] => Array ( [Y] => [W] => [J] => 1 ) [timestamp] => Thu Oct 17 2024 13:58:11 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) [duration] => 12h 05m ) [15:05 31 Dec 2024 IB0719 MAD LHR 18:00 31 Dec 2024 BA0179 LHR JFK] => Array ( [flights] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [i] => 0 [offPeak] => [airlineName] => Iberia [flightNumber] => IB0719 [origin] => MAD [destination] => LHR [stops] => 0 [departure] => 15:05 31 Dec 2024 [arrival] => 16:35 31 Dec 2024 [cabinClasses] => Array ( [Y] => 5 [W] => [J] => 1 ) [aircraft] => Airbus A320 jet ) [1] => Array ( [i] => 1 [offPeak] => [airlineName] => British Airways [flightNumber] => BA0179 [origin] => LHR [destination] => JFK [stops] => 0 [departure] => 18:00 31 Dec 2024 [arrival] => 21:10 31 Dec 2024 [cabinClasses] => Array ( [Y] => 5 [W] => 2 [J] => 1 ) [aircraft] => Boeing 777 jet ) ) [availability] => Array ( [Y] => 5 [W] => 2 [J] => 1 ) [timestamp] => Thu Oct 17 2024 13:58:11 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) [duration] => 12h 05m ) [15:05 31 Dec 2024 IB0719 MAD LHR 19:00 31 Dec 2024 AA0141 LHR JFK] => Array ( [flights] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [i] => 0 [offPeak] => [airlineName] => Iberia [flightNumber] => IB0719 [origin] => MAD [destination] => LHR [stops] => 0 [departure] => 15:05 31 Dec 2024 [arrival] => 16:35 31 Dec 2024 [cabinClasses] => Array ( [Y] => 7 ) [aircraft] => Airbus A320 jet ) [1] => Array ( [i] => 1 [offPeak] => [airlineName] => American Airlines [flightNumber] => AA0141 [origin] => LHR [destination] => JFK [stops] => 0 [departure] => 19:00 31 Dec 2024 [arrival] => 22:05 31 Dec 2024 [cabinClasses] => Array ( [Y] => 7 ) [aircraft] => Boeing 777 jet ) ) [availability] => Array ( [Y] => 7 [W] => [J] => ) [timestamp] => Thu Oct 17 2024 13:58:11 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) [duration] => 13h 00m ) [11:50 31 Dec 2024 EI0593 MAD DUB 16:45 31 Dec 2024 EI0107 DUB JFK] => Array ( [flights] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [i] => 0 [offPeak] => [airlineName] => Aer Lingus [flightNumber] => EI0593 [origin] => MAD [destination] => DUB [stops] => 0 [departure] => 11:50 31 Dec 2024 [arrival] => 13:30 31 Dec 2024 [cabinClasses] => Array ( [Y] => 2 ) [aircraft] => Airbus A320 jet ) [1] => Array ( [i] => 1 [offPeak] => [airlineName] => Aer Lingus [flightNumber] => EI0107 [origin] => DUB [destination] => JFK [stops] => 0 [departure] => 16:45 31 Dec 2024 [arrival] => 19:25 31 Dec 2024 [cabinClasses] => Array ( [Y] => 2 ) [aircraft] => Airbus A330 Jet ) ) [availability] => Array ( [Y] => 2 [W] => [J] => ) [timestamp] => Thu Oct 17 2024 13:58:11 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) [duration] => 13h 35m ) ) )

Any insight into how to parse this code would be appreciated.

It's just two nested loops. foreach ($variable['data'] as $name => $item) { foreach ($item['flights'] as $flight) { ... } }
